# save surf descriptor for future image matching

Tags: android, opencv

I am doing some image comparison task in my `Android` device as in [here](http://morf.lv/modules.php?name=tutorials&lasit=2#.UI35CsXMiqI).

I want to save my feature descriptors of images, then I don't want to recalculate those for later matching  and can use saved descriptors for future matching.

Does any body has experience on this or any idea that how to do this.